# I am getting .asmx file not found exception

Tags: iis, configuration, asmx

Apparently there is some iis configuration issue.  I am getting the the error

System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException : There was no endpoint listening at http.....asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---- System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What should I do?  I don't know anything about iis.  I am just testing some application

Comment: There is an asmx file at the filelocation you're poiting at? Is there routing active? Other files gets served? What does the IIS Log tell you? Is this supposed to be asp.net/mvc/wcf?

Comment: I fixed it by adding the application to iis manager